# Google Custom Search: nocontent tag not properly excluding content

Tags: google-custom-search

On our site we have a Google Custom Search engine set up. I've followed Google's basic instructions, including the part about downloading and reuploading the cse.xml, to get the nocontent tag enabled so we can exclude boilerplate nav content and sidebar content from CSE indexing. We've given it a few weeks to let Google recrawl the site.

However we've noticed in certain instances that Google search is still including content that has the nocontent tag on it.

For example, in doing a search for the phrase "Books & Resources", the search returns results like [this page](http://www2.michaeljfox.org/site/TeamRaiserUser?list_type=custom_donor_list_team_type&team_id=12780&show_amount=SUM&fr_id=1780), in which the only place the search phrase ("Books & Resources") appears is in nav and footer content that clearly has the 'nocontent' tag on its enclosing divs.

I'm not sure if it's related to the fact that it is a page on the www2.michaeljfox.org domain rather than www.michaeljfox.org-- many www2.michaeljfox.org pages show up in the results when you search for any of the phrases in the navigation bar, even though they should be excluded due to the nocontent tags that are on the navigation div.

The nocontent tag also consistently doesn't seem to work on pages with Storify on them: [example](https://www.michaeljfox.org/foundation/news-detail.php?how-to-find-the-right-doctor-for-your-parkinson-treatment).

We'll do a search for a phrase in the nav bar, and get these Storify pages in the results despite the nav bar being nocontent.

Just looking for some feedback in case anyone else has run into a similar problem.